# Default build profile for Maven

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I have added profiling to my Maven project.

```xml
        <profile>
            <id>da</id>                
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>live</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
        </profile>
```

When I give the command `mvn clean install` without specifying the build profile. I need the *dev* profile to be build by default.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

By using the attribute `activeByDefault` you will be able to select a default profile in Maven when no other profile is selected with the -P parameter.

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>da</id>                
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>live</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

See [Maven Introduction to Profiles documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: Beware of [Does using activeByDefault go against maven best practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167206/does-using-activebydefault-go-against-maven-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

You can also activate specific profile by running

```
mvn clean install -Pprod
```

or

```
mvn clean install -Pdev
```

Comment: "When I give the command mvn clean install without specifying the build profile"